# LINQ get items in List<AttributeValuePair>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table on my Database where, aside from other columns (one of which is a UniqueIdentifier) I also have one column where I have a JSON array string with values like this (formatted):

```
[
    {
        "AttributeId": "fe153d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3",
        "AttributeValueId": "64163d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3"
    },
    {
        "AttributeId": "00163d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3",
        "AttributeValueId": "67163d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3"
    }
]
```

I then have this `AttributeValuePair` class which will allow me to read this data on code:

```
public class AttributeValuePair
{
    public AttributeValuePair();

    public Guid AttributeId { get; set; }
    public Guid AttributeValueId { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I get a list of items from this table, I want to be able to filter the resulting array based on only one AttributeValueId and get only the items where this is a match, independently of the value of any other attributes.

Since that on code, to read these attribute collection I must have a `List<AttributeValuePair>`, how in LINQ can I get the items where a particular AttributeValueId is present?

```
List<AttributeValuePair> attributeValuePairs = serializer.Deserialize<List<AttributeValuePair>>(item.Variant);
```

I've been lost at it for two hours already and can't seem to find an escape from this one.

#### EDIT

Being more clear about the problem, what I'm trying to do is, from a `List<ProductVariation>`, get the possible values for the attribute "Portions", when the attribute "Days" is the specified value. I'm having a lot of trouble using the `serializer` to build the LINQ statement.

```
//This code is wrong, I know, but I'm trying to show what I want
result = model.ProductVariations.Find(x, new {serializer.Deserialize<List<AttributeValuePair>>(item.Variant).Where(valuePair => valuePair.AttributeId == attributeId)});
```

Comment: wouln't it be just `attributeValuePairs.Where(a=>a.AttributeId == "00163d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3")` ?

Comment: So, to rephrase it, you want to filter table records that in their JSON string field have items in which (after deserialization) at least one has an `AttributeValueId` equal to some given guid?

Comment: What does your `ProductVariation` class look like? How does the `AttributeValuePair` relate?

Comment: Hello @ertdiddy This class is a Telerik class that comes already with Sitefinity (their CMS). However, the relevant part is that a `ProductVariation`, amongst other data has a property `Variant` which is a string where `AttributeValuePair` are defined in the format I showed above. Aside from this there's also an `Guid Id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was actually a lot simpler than previously expected:

```
public string SelectedVariation(string mealsAttribute, string portionsAttribute, string product)
{
    Guid productId = new Guid(product);
    CatalogManager catalogManager = CatalogManager.GetManager();
    EcommerceManager ecommerceManager = EcommerceManager.GetManager();

    RegisterOrderAccountFormModel model = new RegisterOrderAccountFormModel();
    model.Product = catalogManager.GetProduct(productId);
    List<ProductVariation> productVariationsCollection = catalogManager.GetProductVariations(productId).ToList();

    //This is the really interesting part for the answer:
    return productVariationsCollection.Where(x => x.Variant.ToLower().Contains(mealsAttribute.ToLower()) && x.Variant.ToLower().Contains(portionsAttribute.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault().Id.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
attributeValuePairs.Where(valuePair => valuePair.AttributeId == new Guid("SomeValue"));
```

Comment: This wouldn't match the Guid's case insensitively. Guids that don't match on case are still considered equal.

Comment: Then just do `new Guid("someValue")`

Comment: This approach works (this one I had already achieved in the meantime) but what is boggling me is the part I've added to the original question, which I can't seem to get right..